# Azure VPN Site to Site Gateway Performance

Tags: vpn, performance, azure

I have an Azure Hosted Terminal Server with a secure VPN Gateway back to my Trusted LAN.

A couple of applications run fairly slow. Client on Azure TS accessing data on Local LAN via gateway.

I was expecting that the upgrade of our leased line from 20MB to 100MB would have improved the lag, but there is no noticeable improvement.

Is there anything I can configure in Azure that would improve response times?

TIA, Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several factors may affect the throughput of VPN: Network bandwidth, network latency, VPN server performance and so on.

The ICMP message is blocked on Azure, to check the latency, you can use a tool called [port query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=24009). If the latency is too large, then please choose a nearest datacenter to deploy your applications and gateway. If it still doesn't work, then you should consult with your ISP about this problem.

Also, please check the performance of your local VPN server. If it is a dedicated hardware, then you need to check the supported throughput of IPsec VPN of this device.